# Angularjs model does not render when change in DWR call back

Tags: angularjs, dwr

I have a problem when try to change 'model' in DWR call back.

```
function mainCtrl($scope) {
     $scope.mymodel = "x";  // this is ok
     DWRService.searchForSomething(function(result){
           $scope.mymodel = result; // PROBLEM!!! it does not rerender the new value
     }
     $scope.mymodel = "y";  // this is also ok.
}
```

Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not super familiar with DWR, but my guess is that you need an $scope.$apply to enclose your model change. Like so:

```
function mainCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.mymodel = "x";  // this is ok
   DWRService.searchForSomething(function(result){
       $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.mymodel = result; // PROBLEM!!! it does not rerender the new value
       });
   });
   $scope.mymodel = "y";  // this is also ok.
}
```

Comment: Wow, it works! Thanks! I never see $scope.$apply() in tutorial.

Comment: Your welcome - There do seem to be a bunch of angular details that are easy to miss.

Answer (score 0):

just to clarify urban_racoons answer:
DWR makes an Asynchronous call to the server. So the result is also received asynchronously.

Asynchronous change in model is not detected by AngularJs (reference [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TRrL5j3MIvo)). To make the change effective you have to call $scope.apply() (as done by urban_racoons).

Another way to write above code is:

```
function mainCtrl($scope) {
     $scope.mymodel = "x";  // this is ok
     DWRService.searchForSomething(function(result){
           $scope.mymodel = result; // PROBLEM!!! it does not rerender the new value
           $scope.apply();
     }
     $scope.mymodel = "y";  // this is also ok.
}
```