# Can I use DWR function in Angular.js?

Tags: angularjs, dwr

My team member is familiar with `java` & `DWR` , I want use `angular.js` at frontend . So my question is whether the two will work well ? Thanks.

Comment: I would be very interested too. Any news? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they can be made to work.

Check out one of the problem discussed [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18670458/angularjs-model-does-not-render-when-change-in-dwr-call-back/39022927#39022927).

```
function mainCtrl($scope) {
     $scope.mymodel = "x";  // this is ok
     DWRService.searchForSomething(function(result){
           $scope.mymodel = result; // PROBLEM!!! it does not rerender the new value
     }
     $scope.mymodel = "y";  // this is also ok.
}
```